# Angular Material Listen Class Changes

Tags: angular, angular-material2, viewchild

I am using Angular 5 and am trying to listen for class changes on an Angular Material Form field `mat-form-field`. Specifically, I want to know when `ng-pristine`, `ng-dirty`, `ng-untouched`, `ng-touched`, `ng-invalid` and `mat-focused` are added to the `mat-form-field` by AM's logic.

I've tried various approaches using `@ViewChild`, `@HostListener` and `@HostBinding` that I found on StackOverflow. Below is an example for the `mat-form-field` with `#firstNameRegister`:

```
@ViewChild('firstNameRegister') firstNameRegister: ElementRef;
ngDoCheck() {
    if(this.firstNameRegister.nativeElement.classList.contains('ng-dirty')) 
    {
        console.log('Is Dirty');
    }
}
```

The issue I get regardless of approach is that `#firstNameRegister` is somehow seen as `undefined` and thus, the `.nativeElement` call fails. Is there something specific with Angular Material's components that prevents them from being observed for class changes?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming you're using reactive forms. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10887) in the angular repository for adding streams for the various form control status changes with some comments that may help your design direction. Instead of running your check in ```ngDoCheck()``` which would have heavy performance penalties, consider moving the logic to the form control's ```valueChanges``` observable, as documented [here](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#observe-control-changes).

Comment: Thank you for this explanation!